# Php array reconstruction

Tags: php, arrays

On my server side I receive following format of request:

```
"medium x 1, small x 2"
```

How can I transform these data in this format:

```
array(0:{"medium"=>1},1:{"small"=>2})
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You want to convert your string into an array. Did you tried anything? Yes then post your attempts too.

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: @Uchiha ya, I almost forget that the request is not in the form of array. It's a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple, harnessing `explode()` and looping with `foreach() {...}`:

```
$str = "medium x 1, small x 2";
$a = explode(",", $str);

$data = array();
foreach($a as $s) {
    list($size, $quantity) = explode('x', $s);
    $data[] = array($size => $quantity);
}
// show it
print(json_encode($data));
```

Which returns:

```
[{"medium ":" 1"},{" small ":" 2"}]
```

[**Demo/Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#s9BzivAh3)